# How to obtain Indy version of RadStudio XE5 without installing XE5

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-xe5, indy10

I would like to know the version of Indy10 (e.g. Indy 10.5.8.3) of the RadStudio XE5.

The help is included in the H2 compiled help, but not on the docwiki. I tried to find on the internet, but I am not successful.

I am currently using XE4. I would like to know the change in the function signatures of the Indy functions between XE4 and XE5, if any.

Are there any way to know the version without installing XE5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to know the version of Indy10 (e.g. Indy 10.5.8.3) of the RadStudio XE5.

XE5 shipped with Indy 10.6.0.5040.

> The help is included in the H2 compiled help, but not on the docwiki. I tried to find on the internet, but I am not successful.

Indy is not an Embarcadero product, so it is not included in Embarcadero's DocWiki.  [Indy documentation](http://indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/index.EN.aspx) is available for download from Indy's website (although, it is a bit outdated, but there is effort under way to slowly bring it up-to-date in the future).

> I am currently using XE4. I would like to know the change in the function signatures of the Indy functions between XE4 and XE5, if any.

I would suggest you download the XE5 release of Indy and do a diff against your XE4 version.  You can download specific releases of Indy from Indy's SVN server directly, or the latest SVN revision from nightly SVN snapshots on Indy's Fulgan mirror.  [Instructions](http://indyproject.org/Sockets/Download/DevSnapshot.EN.aspx) for accessing both are on Indy's website.

I can tell you that Indy 10.6.0 had some big interface changes over 10.5.x ([I blogged about some of them](http://indyproject.org/Sockets/Blogs/ChangeLog/20130423.EN.aspx)), but XE4 also shipped with Indy 10.6 (10.6.0.4975, to be exact).  I could not tell you offhand what the changes between the XE4 and XE5 releases were, so you will just have to run your own diffs.

> Are there any way to know the version without installing XE5.

Embarcadero releases of Indy from RAD Studio 2010 onwards (minus XE3, however) have been tagged in Indy's SVN.  You can browse the SVN repository directly if you want to know which source code is in each release.

Comment: Thank you very much. You have replied all of what I needed. I am grateful.